# Jmeter CSV data config element not working

Tags: csv, jmeter, load-testing, multi-user

I have created jmeter script for load testing and added CSV data element to read Username and Password of 300 Users.Also followed below steps;

- Created CSV file using a notepad and stored it in a directory where created script stored.
- Defined variables and file path in CSV data set element
- Used variables as parameters of HTTP request
- Increased number of Threads

But it doesn't worked as expected.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary reduce threads count to 1-2, add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect request and response details.

If don't see proper username/password combination in the request body - your script is misconfigured. Check out [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for detailed setup instructions.

If you see valid username/password pair but login is not successful, follow below checklist:

1. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan
2. If point 1 doesn't help - check for dynamic request parameters. Probably you'll need to extract some value from the first response (when you execute GET request for the login page) with the [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), convert it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and add it as a parameter to the request which performs login.